# java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString() on a null object reference, LogCat shows this error at line 202

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the download Url based on the condition that the image path for the storage reference is null or not.

I tried to put the whole code inside the if else statement instead of just assigning the value to download_uri inside the condition which resolves the error. I am not able to understand why this approach works and another one doesn't.

```
    mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name=mProfileName.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && mainImageUri!=null){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(isChanged){
                //The task of storing the data goes through uploading the image as well.

            user_id = mUser.getUid();

            final StorageReference image_path= mStorageReference.child("profile_photo").child(user_id+".jpg");
            image_path.putFile(mainImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                         if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            storeFireStore(image_path,name);
                         }else{
                             String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                             Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this,"Image Error: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         }
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            });

        }else{
                    //The task of storing the data does not go through uploading the image.
                    storeFireStore(null,name);
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

}

```
private void storeFireStore(StorageReference image_path, final String name) {
    final Uri[] download_uri = new Uri[1];
    if(image_path!=null){
        image_path.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                download_uri[0] =uri;
                Log.d(TAG,"Download Url obtained");
            }
        });
        } else{
        download_uri[0] =mainImageUri;
        Log.d(TAG,"Download Url obtained in else");
    }

Map<String,String> userMap=new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("image", download_uri[0].toString());//line 202 this is 
where the error occurs.userMap.put("name",name);
```

I expect to get the downLoad_uri but it provides a null value

Answer (score 1):

`image_path.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the results of the operation are complete.  Your code goes on to access the `download_uri` array which is initialized with null values.  You can only expect the array to have a populated value after the callback completes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are doing unnecessary work to get download URL of image if you can do it by just simple on line of code.

Just use below code to upload image in firebase storage.

```
    image_path.putFile(mainImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
         if(task.isSuccessful()){

           // HERE YOU CAN DIRECTLY GET DOWNLOAD URL OF UPLOADED IMAGE USING TASK RESULT.
           String downloadUrl = String.valueOf(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
           storeFireStore(downloadUrl,name);

         } else {

           String error = task.getException().getMessage();
           Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this,"Image Error: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
         mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
    });
```

And make change in `storeFireStore` method like below,

```
    private void storeFireStore(String image_path, final String name) {

        Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("image", image_path != null ? image_path : "");//line 202 this is where the error occurs.
        userMap.put("name", name);

    }
```